# A definition for finite sets in Agda

Tags: agda

I am new to Agda.  I'm reading the paper "Dependent Types at Work" by Ana Bove and Peter Dybjer.  I don't understand the discussion of Finite Sets (on page 15 in my copy).

The paper defines a `Fin` type:

```
data Fin : Nat -> Set where
    fzero : {n : Nat} -> Fin (succ n)
    fsucc : {n : Nat} -> Fin n -> Fin (succ n)
```

I must be missing something obvious.  I don't understand how this definition works.  Could someone simply translate the definition of `Fin` into everyday English?  That might be all I need to understand this part of the paper.

Thanks for taking the time to read my question.  I appreciate it.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
data Fin : Nat -> Set where
```

Fin is a data type parametrized by a natural number (or: `Fin` is a type-level function which takes a `Nat` and returns a `Set` (basic type), i.e. for any natural number `n`, `Fin n` is a `Set`).

```
    fzero : {n : Nat} -> Fin (succ n)
```

For all natural numbers `n`, `fzero` is a member of the type/set `Fin (succ n)`, from which follows that for all positive numbers `n` (i.e. all naturals except zero), `fzero` is a member of `Fin n`.

```
    fsucc : {n : Nat} -> Fin n -> Fin (succ n)
```

For all natural numbers `n` and all values `m` of type `Fin n`, `fsucc m` is a member of type `Fin (succ n)`.

---

So `fzero` is a member of `Fin n` for all `n` except zero and `fsucc m` is a member of `Fin n` for all `n` that represent a number greater than `fsucc m`.

Basically `Fin n` represents the Set of all natural numbers smaller than `n`, i.e. of all valid indices for lists of size `n`.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question.  Your explanation is clear and easy to understand. This is exactly what I needed. Thanks again.